# Crystal Report with two tables?

Tags: crystal-reports, reporting, crystal-reports-2008

I am attempting to write a Crystal report based on 2 unique tables.

One is named IAgentQueueStats, and another is AgentActivityLog.

I need to be able to display both tables data on the same report. They are not related to each other.

Parameters: Date Time

The user enters a starting date and an ending date.

IAgentQueueStats.dIntervalStart I do this: in {@Start Date} to {@End Date}

Now AgentActivityLog has a value AgentActivityLog.StatusDateTime

How can you use 2 unique tables for a single report? Is this even possible?

Comment: Since they are not related you'll have to describe how you intend to display the data. Perhaps you're looking to interleave the data based on timestamps only. That would probably involve a union.

Comment: Try using sub reports